# Add parameter to iframe source

Tags: php, android, html, iframe, android-webview

i need to display an iframe in my Android app WebView, the iframe exists in an HTML file that sit on a Web server. 
I need to add a parameter to the iframe source before i display it in the WebView depending on the user input.

My php code:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $intamount = (int)$amount;
        echo $intamount;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['currency'])){

        $currency = $_POST['currency'];
        $intcurrency = (int)$currency;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['lan'])){

        $lan = $_POST["lan"];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])){

        $email_address = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['name'])){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }




    $iframe_source = 'https://sampleurl.php?sum='.$intamount.'&currency='.$intcurrency.'&cred_type=1&trButtonColor=008080&email='.$email_address.'&contact='.$name;

    echo $iframe_source;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>



    </head>

    <body>


        <iframe width="370" height="455" src="<?php
            echo $iframe_source;
        ?>" frameborder="5" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>

</html>
```

Can i make a post request to a php file for example to do this? If yes, is there a way to add the html code inside a php file and display it in my WebView? 
Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not a real source it is just an example, i need to be able to adjust it fro my Android app depending on the user input

Comment: Sure, sampleurl is just an example, the real one is in the format you provided, and it is working fine, i guess is that the iframe is displayed just before the parameters are being received, and it might be the reason why i am getting that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not loading a PHP  form your web server after you receiver the user input.

You can do a POST or GET request.

So the instate of loading `http://example.com/webview.html` do `http://example.com/webview.php?user_paramter=value`

Now the `webview.php` looks basically the same es the `webview.html` with some small changes:

```
<?php
    $user_paramter = $_GET['user_paramter'];
    $link = 'https:iframedemo.php?sum=13&currency=1&user_paramter=' . $user_paramter;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="370" height="455" src="<?php
            echo $link;
        ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your App will receive a HTML file that has the right iframe source/Link

If this the the PHP script is recived before user input, than `$_POST` or `$_GET` is empty and nothing will work.  So if you do `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning of your PHP Script and you have something like `array(0) {}` than the problem is not the PHP Script or the iframe itself. You have to find a way how the page is called after user input.

Comment: Maybe you could dele all the comands on the question and on the answer so the hole thing do not look so messy